# jQuery ConceptMap plug-in bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is about the jQuery plugin ConceptMap:
https://github.com/allain/JavaScript-Concept-Map

There is also a rewrite of this plug-in by KNV:
https://github.com/knv/jquery-conceptmap-plugin

These plug-ins draw "concept maps."  both demos show the maps at the top of the screen.  however, if you put any html elements above the div container holding the map, the elements on the map get all messed up- their positions do not shift properly within the browser window in response to the html elements added at the top of the page.

I've tried contacting both developers for a fix but no response. I've messed around with the javascript code in these plug-ins with no success.  anyone out there able to fix it?  to reproduce the problem i'm seeing, all you have to do is download either plug-in package and edit the demos.  just add an <h1> or any other html element to the top of the page above the <div id="container"> element.  you'll see the map gets messed up after that.

thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

the problem in http://knv.github.com/jquery-conceptmap-plugin/textarea.html
is in css,try use

```
#container {
background-color: #EEEEEE;
position: relative;
}
```

insteadof

```
#container {
background-color: #EEEEEE; 
}
```

it must fix your problem, tell me if it is ok 8)

Comment: Did you actually try this yourself?  What you suggest did not fix the problem for me.